# Prüfer group is divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra

I cannot understand the proof at last line of point 3 in page 1 of

http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/algebra/kaplan/ModThe/modex11sol.pdf

I particular I do not understand the following inequality
$x^{ap}.x^{bq}=x^{bq}$

It will be very helpful if someone tells me the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the text one must be $ap^i + bq = 1$ instead of $ap + bq = 1$, where $x^{p^i}=1$.

Comment: @Novikov - Thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome.